# declarative way of initializing kendo datePicker fails

Tags: html, kendo-ui, datepicker

Whats wrong here with declarative way?

[dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@Skumar/IZiROVOd)

Initializing with Javascript works well.
But not the data- attribute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing kendo binding.

Kendo.bind($('body')); preferably in master page.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your script to get the data content from the tag:

```
$("#yourElementId").kendoDatePicker({
                start: $("#monthpicker").data("start"),                          
                depth: $("#monthpicker").data("depth"),                           
                format: $("#monthpicker").data("format")
 });
```

Comment: I'm defining my datePicker using Taghelper approach, Declarative way is better suited. Hence avoiding definition through javascript.